How to implement fuzzy search in Laravel?
I was trying to do fuzzy search in Laravel as if someone can give wrong spelling then it should get a related result for example :if car name is nissan and the user misspelled it nessan then it should show the correct Nissan and the related one i am already using like operator but for the full spelling its is giving not found. can anybody here tell me what will be the best approach to do this?
I have tried making LEVENSHTEIN function in mysql but it is not required for me, i have tried soundex but it's not that accurate. Is there any way that i can do this in Laravel ?

Laravel scout with Typesense

chat-gpt will give you few ideas to implement
